# Why do I need enable multidex if I do not reach 64k limitation?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-multidex

I read about this problem with method limitation 64k and Multi-dex flag.
Set Multi-dex, works for me!
But I check my app with https://github.com/google/android-classyshark and it says my app has methods-count: 30925

So how is it possible that I have "java.exe" exited with code 2 error? Any ideas?

Comment: Libraries' methods also count, not only code you write.

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

> When your app and the libraries it references exceed 65,536 methods, you encounter a build error that indicates your app has reached the limit of the Android build architecture

I have read somewhere that,

App Compat contains ~16k methods
Google Play Services GCM contains ~17k methods

Here, you might be using libraries that might be using other libraries. So you might want to try other tools to check actual method counts.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought this app will show me final number that Im using. 
Tnx